# Should Cargo.lock be committed when the crate is both a rust library and an executable?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I 've read https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/cargo-toml-vs-cargo-lock.html

If I understand correctly, when I commit Cargo.lock into my crate (which is both a library and an executable)'s repository, and also, publish it to crates.io, downstream crates will ignore it and build it's own snap, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the best practice from the excellent project [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), which **split's itself into several crates**. For the binary crate in the root, they track Cargo.lock, but for library crates that provide functionality for the application (for example, [pcre2](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/tree/master/crates/pcre2)), they don't.

Comment: This is misleading because the pcre2 package in ripgrep is actually part of the workspace defined in the root Cargo.toml and a workspace always shares a single Cargo.lock in the root.

Comment: @Danielhu please edit the answer. ripgrep uses workspaces and as such uses the same Cargo.lock for the binary as well as the libraries.

Answer (score 26):

Yes, crates that depend on your library will ignore your `Cargo.lock`. The Cargo FAQ provides [more details](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/faq.html#why-do-binaries-have-cargolock-in-version-control-but-not-libraries):

> #### Why do binaries have `Cargo.lock` in version control, but not libraries?
>
> The purpose of a `Cargo.lock` is to describe the state of the world at the time
> of a successful build. It is then used to provide deterministic builds across
> whatever machine is building the package by ensuring that the exact same
> dependencies are being compiled.
>
> This property is most desirable from applications and packages which are at the
> very end of the dependency chain (binaries). As a result, it is recommended that
> all binaries check in their `Cargo.lock`.
>
> For libraries the situation is somewhat different. A library is not only used by
> the library developers, but also any downstream consumers of the library. Users
> dependent on the library will not inspect the library’s `Cargo.lock` (even if it
> exists). This is precisely because a library should **not** be deterministically
> recompiled for all users of the library.
>
> If a library ends up being used transitively by several dependencies, it’s
> likely that just a single copy of the library is desired (based on semver
> compatibility). If Cargo used all of the dependencies' `Cargo.lock` files,
> then multiple copies of the library could be used, and perhaps even a version
> conflict.
>
> In other words, libraries specify semver requirements for their dependencies but
> cannot see the full picture. Only end products like binaries have a full
> picture to decide what versions of dependencies should be used.